# Can't print the result of a function within a sub

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I've created a macro to scrape proxies from a free proxy site. The macro is capable of producing list of proxies. However, my intention is to print the proxy list within this subroutine `PrintProxies` from the function `GenerateProxy`. I don't understand how to return the collection of result from that function which can eventually be printed within the subroutine.

I've tried with:

```
Function GenerateProxy() As Variant
    Dim oHttp As New ServerXMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim iCol As New Collection, pIP$, pPort$, elem As Object
    
    With oHttp
        .Open "GET", "https://www.us-proxy.org/", True
        .send
        While .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        For Each elem In Html.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")
            If InStr(elem.innerText, "yes") > 0 Then
                pIP = elem.getElementsByTagName("td")(0).innerText
                pPort = elem.getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innerText
                iCol.Add pIP & ":" & pPort
            End If
        Next elem
    End With
    GenerateProxy = iCol.count
End Function

Sub PrintProxies()
    Dim iCol As New Collection
    iCol = GenerateProxy()
    MsgBox "proxy list: " & iCol
End Sub
```

When I execute the script, I see an error `Compile error: Argument not Optional` pointing at this line `iCol = GenerateProxy()`.

> How can I print the result within the sub?

`There was a typo which was causing that error. Now it is fixed`

***Solution***

```
Function GenerateProxy() As Collection
    Dim oHttp As New ServerXMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim iCol As New Collection, pIP$, pPort$, elem As Object
 
    With oHttp
        .Open "GET", "https://www.us-proxy.org/", True
        .send
        While .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        For Each elem In Html.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")
            If InStr(elem.innerText, "yes") > 0 Then
                pIP = elem.getElementsByTagName("td")(0).innerText
                pPort = elem.getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innerText
                Debug.Print pIP & ":" & pPort
                iCol.Add pIP & ":" & pPort
            End If
        Next elem
    End With
 
    Set GenerateProxy = iCol
End Function
 
Sub PrintProxies()
    Dim iCol As Collection, col As Variant
 
    Set iCol = GenerateProxy
    For Each col In iCol
        Debug.Print col
    Next col
End Sub
```

Comment: Change 'Function GenerateProxy() As Variant' to 'Function GenerateProxy() As Collection'.  Then change 'GenerateProxy = iCol.count' to 'Set GenerateProxy = iCol'.  Finally in PrintProxies change 'iCol = GenerateProxy()' to 'Set iCol = GenerateProxy'.  You will then need a loop to iterate over the iCol collection to print each item.

Comment: Two other items. 1. Read up on the Set keyword.  2.  Don't use Variants if a specific type will do the job.  Variants have a key role in VBA but should not be used in the way you have.

Comment: You should edit your original question to add your current code as an update.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```vb
Sub PrintProxies()

    Dim iCol As Long

    iCol = GenerateProxy()
    MsgBox "proxy list: " & iCol

End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, at least there is some result. Can I not print the total collection `iCol` instead of that `iCol.count`? Thanks.

Comment: Sure. You have the count, so create a `For .. Next` loop that prints each item of the collection.